# How do I calculate the price upon entering the quantity but also show its quantity when the add and minus button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So what I wanted to do was to also calculate the unit price according to what number was entered. I was already able to update the quantity of the product and then calculate its unit price and also its total amount.

My problem now is how can I also allow the user to enter the quantity of the product. And also still retain the functionality to increase and decrease the product.

I have recreated this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-to-cart-sampled-2-with-table-efqrhd?file=/src/Cart.js

```
const Cart = ({ cartItems, handleCartClearance, handleRemove, handleAdd }) => {
  const [inputQty, setInputQty] = useState(0);
  console.log(cartItems, "items");

  const totalAmount = cartItems.reduce(
    (price, item) => price + item.quantity * item.price,
    0
  );

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(cartItems, "order");
  };

  console.log(
    "test",
    cartItems.reduce((prev, item) => {
      if (!prev[item.id]) prev[item.id] = { ...item, nest: [] };
      prev[item.id].nest.push({ ...item });
      return prev;
    }, {})
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        Order page
        {cartItems.length >= 1 && (
          <Button onClick={handleCartClearance}>Clear Orders</Button>
        )}
        {cartItems.length === 0 && <div>No Items in the cart</div>}
        <div>
          {Object.entries(
            cartItems.reduce((prev, item) => {
              if (!prev[item.id]) prev[item.id] = { ...item, nest: [] };
              prev[item.id].nest.push(item);
              return prev;
            }, {})
          ).map(([id, obj], idx) => (
            <TableContainer key={id + obj.color} component={Paper}>
              <Table aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell align="center">
                      Product Name: {obj.name + " " + obj.size}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell colspan={3}></TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Color</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Qty</TableCell>
                    <TableCell></TableCell>

                    <TableCell>Unit Price</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {obj.nest.map((nest, idx) => (
                    <TableRow key={idx}>
                      <TableCell>{nest.color}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>
                        <input
                          style={{ width: "1rem" }}
                          value={nest.quantity}
                        />
                      </TableCell>

                      <TableCell align="right">
                        <IconButton
                          onClick={(e) =>
                            handleAdd(
                              nest.id,
                              nest.prodName,
                              nest.price,
                              nest.size,
                              nest.cat,
                              nest.color
                            )
                          }
                        >
                          <AddIcon color="success" />
                        </IconButton>

                        <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemove(nest)}>
                          <RemoveIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>
                        {Number(nest.quantity) * Number(nest.price)}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          ))}
         
          <div>
            <b>Total Amount :{totalAmount}</b>
          </div>
          {cartItems.length >= 1 && <Button type="submit">Save Order</Button>}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Additional Answer from the answer below to only accept whole numbers:

```
 <input
                            style={{ width: "1rem" }}
                            value={nest.quantity}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                              if (e.target.value === "0") {
                                return handleRemove(nest);
                              }
                              const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
                              if (
                                e.target.value === "" ||
                                re.test(e.target.value)
                              ) {
                                handleAdd(
                                  nest.id,
                                  nest.prodName,
                                  nest.price,
                                  nest.size,
                                  nest.cat,
                                  nest.color,
                                  e.target.value
                                );
                              }
                            }}
                          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an addition to your `handleAdd` function to pass in another `quan` argument.  Then add an `onChange` to your input to call `handleAdd` and pass in the optional `quan` value as `e.target.value`.

```
  const handleAdd = (id, name, price, size, cat, color, quan = null) => {
    console.log("add", id, name, price, size, cat, color, quan);
    const productExist = cartItems.find(
      (item) => item.id === id && item.color === color
    );

    if (productExist) {
      setCartItems(
        cartItems.map((item) =>
          item.id === id && item.color === color
            ? { ...productExist, quantity: quan === "" || quan ? quan: +productExist.quantity + 1 }
            : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      setCartItems([
        ...cartItems,
        { id, name, price, size, cat, color, quantity: 1 }
      ]);
    }
  };
```

```
<input
  style={{ width: "1rem" }}
  value={nest.quantity}
  onChange={(e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "0") {
      return handleRemove(nest)
    }
    handleAdd(
      nest.id,
      nest.prodName,
      nest.price,
      nest.size,
      nest.cat,
      nest.color,
      e.target.value
    )
  }
  }
/>
```

Notice I added some error handling for a 0 value being passed from the input. There may be additional steps for you to figure out how to handle negative values, decimal values, etc.

One "gotcha" when working with inputs: the value coming back from it is a *string* not an integer.  To keep things consistent as integers, I added the `+` operator to the front on any quantity math I need to perform. Here is a link to [Unary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) so you can get familiar with the usage of `+`.

Comment: Thank you, I've also managed to solve where the input would only accept whole numbers. I've posted it for future reference for other people